# iPhone 6s Plus Home Screen rotates on tilt

Tags: ios, iphone

On my iPhone 6 Plus, the home screen rotates on tilt, but on my iPhone 6s it doesn't rotate, is it ok? My iPhone 6 Plus is running iOS 8.1 and my iPhone 6s is running iOS 9.

Comment: Yeah, the rotation for the apps only happens on the Plus phones.  The standard size phones do not rotate the apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6S Plus rotate in the Springboard like an iPad. Smaller iPhones do not rotate like that. There are no settings on the small iPhone models to get this behavior.